Android app capable of real-time data streaming from BLE devices
I am looking for Android app that can establish connections with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices and stream their data in real-time. I am working on a project that requires continuous data streaming from BLE devices, and I need recommendations for reliable software solutions that can facilitate this functionality effectively.
Key desires:

Android application capable of connecting to BLE devices.
Ability to stream real-time data from app to maybe REST/websocket endpoint.
Support for stable connections and consistent data transmission.
(BONUS) Features for processing, displaying, or analyzing the streamed data within the app.

Recommendations based on personal experiences or expert insights for robust and reliable apps are welcomed!

So you are looking for an app-version of socat with BLE support? Note that BLE/Bluetooth is not as simple as TCP where you simply have to select the port. BLE requires to specify a UUID for the characteristic that can be read or write or read/write. For reading you need an additional characteristic for notification. And there is also the maximum packet size and other details. Therefore most BLE are specific for a certain client system and not general usage apps. IMHO your question is too generic regarding the BLE clients to be supported and the TCP endpoints to be supported.
